# Format data in Google Analytics API response and visualize with Charts API

Tags: google-analytics, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

I am building a reports page for my clients to be able to view their data in a format they are already familiar with. Up to this point they receive a .pdf with select metrics and explanations. I want to automate this using Google Analytics Embed API. I am having trouble formatting data before drawing the charts. Specifically I want to display Avg Session Duration in a 00:00:00 time format rather than a decimal. Also, I would like to truncate Pages / Session down to two decimal places.

Here is the code for the chart I am drawing:

```
 /**
         * Create a table chart showing top Keywords by sessions with average session duration and pages / session
        */

        var keywordChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
          query: {
            'dimensions': 'ga:keyword',
            'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:pageviewsPerSession',
            'sort': '-ga:sessions',
            'start-date': '30daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'yesterday',
            'max-results': '10'
          },
          chart: {
            type: 'TABLE',
            container: 'keyword-chart-container',
            options: {
              width: '100%'
            }
          }
        });

        keywordChart.on('success', function(response) {
          console.log(response.data.cols[2]);
        });
```

I appreciate any help or insight, thank you for your time!

---

EDIT

---

I have changed my code to use the google analytics API along with the Charts API, however I am still having issues getting the Avg Session Duration to format using a date pattern.
Here is my updated code:

```
var keywordChart = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
  query: {
    'dimensions': 'ga:keyword',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:pageviewsPerSession',
    'sort': '-ga:sessions',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday',
    'max-results': '10',
    'output': 'dataTable'
  }
});

keywordChart.on('success', function(response) {
  console.log(response.dataTable);
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.dataTable);
  var timeFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'H:mm:ss'});
  var numFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({fractionDigits: 2});

  timeFormatter.format(data, 2);
  numFormatter.format(data, 3);

  var keywordsTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('keyword-chart-container'));
  keywordsTable.draw(data);

});
```

I need to divide the data in data[2] by (24*60*60) before applying the pattern as well.

data[2]/(24*60*60) to then be put into the pattern 'H:mm:ss' before my table is drawn.

I am having trouble finding in the Charts documentation how to accomplish this.

Again any insight is much appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: The `gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart` is a convenience function in which they make it easy to quickly generate a chart at the expense of handling the API response. Basically it applies the glue between the [`gapi.client.analytics.data.ga`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/using-components#analytics_client_library) and the [Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery). If you are up to the task simply use the embed API to query the Analytics API, format the response, and then pass it to the charts API.

Comment: You should also [check out the demo site using the embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/third-party-visualizations/) to figure out what is possible.

Comment: In order to format the response from the embed API I would leave the chart value empty? In the on.('success', function(response){  format and pass to Charts API here  }?

Comment: I have checked out the demo site along with searching on Stack Overflow and the Github issues on the corresponding repo. I was not able to find a concrete solution or example of how to format data and pass it to the Charts API.

Comment: can you share a sample of `response.dataTable`? when using a formatter, the column type must be the format type, i.e. -- to use `DateFormat`, the column type must be `'date'`

Comment: What I am suggesting is to query the reporting API directly, process the results into the desired [format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) and construct the [Data Table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datatables_dataviews). There are examples of each of these steps it is just a matter of putting them together. The embed API component is a convenience function made of those component pieces. But because you never use actually handle the data directly in the embed API DataChart component there is not a way to format it.

Comment: @WhiteHat the column type is `'number'` is it possible to change the type?

Answer (score 2):

you can use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) to replace `data[2]` with a [calculated column](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_setColumns)

assuming `data[2]` is a time value and will result in a valid date
`new Date(data[2])`

see following snippet...

```
keywordChart.on('success', function(response) {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.dataTable);

  var timeFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'H:mm:ss'});

  // create view
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  // include all columns from data
  var columns = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    columns.push(i);
  }

  // replace date column with calculation
  columns[2] = {
    calc: function (dt, r) {
      return {
        // value
        v: new Date(dt.getValue(r, 2)),
        // formatted value
        f: timeFormatter.formatValue(new Date(dt.getValue(r, 2)))};
    },
    type: 'date',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(2)
  };
  view.setColumns(columns);

  var keywordsTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('keyword-chart-container'));
  // draw chart with view
  keywordsTable.draw(view);
});
```

obviously, you could do the same with the number column using `numFormatter`

Comment: It does help, thank you! I am still having trouble getting the date to format correctly. The value in the field is the number of seconds that an average session lasted. In order to display it in a 00:00:00 format I need to calculate (value in field) / (24*60*60) before formatting it.   `timeFormatter.formatValue(new Date(dt.getValue(r, 2))/(24*60*60))};` returns NaN:NaN:NaN and `timeFormatter.formatValue(new Date(dt.getValue(r, 2)/(24*60*60)))};` returns the wrong value.

Comment: How are you getting the analytics API and Chart API to load together. When I add the Chart API I get JS errors. But without it I can do all the chart stuff I need but can't format numbers.

Comment: i personally don't use the analytics API, just charts -- but `google.visualization` has its own [formatters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) -- with [`NumberFormat`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat), format a column in a DataTable using the `format` method, or an individual number value using the `formatValue` method